# How to get first two words from a string?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to get first two words from a string

For example, from this sentence below (field *name*):

`One Two Three Four Five`

I only want to get 'One Two'

I have tried the code below, but it only gave me the first word.

`SELECT SUBSTR(name, 1, STRPOS(name, ' '))`

Is there any way for me to get the result that I want? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `REGEXP_EXTRACT(sentence, r'\w+\s+\w+')`

for example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'One Two Three Four Five' sentence
)
SELECT sentence, REGEXP_EXTRACT(sentence, r'\w+\s+\w+') AS first_two_words
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

outputs

```
Row sentence                    first_two_words  
1   One Two Three Four Five     One Two
```

Also consider adjusted version as below if you need to handle edge case when there is only one word in a sentence

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'One Two Three Four Five' sentence UNION ALL
  SELECT 'One'
)
SELECT sentence, REGEXP_EXTRACT(sentence, r'\w+(?:\s+\w+)?') AS first_two_words  
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row sentence                    first_two_words  
1   One Two Three Four Five     One Two  
2   One                         One
```

You can read more about REGEXP_EXTRACT [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract)

Also, note: BigQuery provides regular expression support using the [re2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) library; see that documentation for its regular expression syntax.

Comment: Hi Mikhail, do you have any reference so that I could learn about REGEX in BigQuery that also provides example? Thanks